# Creating a new record using a One to Many relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I have a sample relation between two models, User and Announcement as displayed below.

```
class Announcement extends Model
{
    //
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    //
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function announcements(){
        return $this->hasMany(Announcement::class);
    }
}
```

Currently I am trying to create a new announcement, using the relation but it throws an error
`"message": "Call to a member function announcements() on null",`

This is the current state of my `api` from the `controller`

```
class AnnouncementController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $record = request()->user()->announcements()->create($this->validateRequest());

        return (new AnnouncementResoure($record))
                    ->response()
                    ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }

    private function validateRequest()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'title'=> 'required|Min:3',
            'comment' => 'required'
        ]);
    }


}
```

I don't seem to know what could e responsible for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `request()->user()`  replace it with `auth('api')->user();` or `$request->user('api');`

Comment: Call to undefined function `App\Http\Controllers\API\user()`